# How to Clear Cache of Visual Studio 2010, Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in my projects. First I do the following:

1. Start Visual Studio
2. Select Project >> Add New Items >> Ado.Net Entity Data Model
3. Select Generate From Database and Next
4. Click New Connection Button And Connect To Oracle
5. Connect
6. Finish

Then I Disconnect From Oracle Server:

1. In Visual Studio
2. Project >> Add New Items >> Ado.Net Entity Data Model
3. Select Generate From Database and Next

Then the Oracle Connection Wizard opened automatically, and I closed the connection dialog box, and the Entity Framework Wizard closed immediately.
I cannot connect to any server after this step.

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean. Can you describe step-by-step which actions you do, using names of buttons/menu items?

Comment: Ah. Much better! But could you generate a new model at all without database connection? I think in that case you can only create an empty model ("Empty Model" in stead of "Generate From Database").

Comment: YES, Thank you.
This is a Wizard Bug.
in Empty Model i can Right Click And Select Update Model.

Comment: To resolve this issue I have made these step and it solved [Entity Data Model wizard disappears Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178496/entity-data-model-wizard-disappears-sql-anywhere-17/42554921#42554921)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but I've had similar issues (Visual Studio crashed when I open a file). Try deleting the `.suo` file in the main folder of your project and see.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio wizard picks automatically the first connection listed on data connections when you open the database explorer.

If you delete/update the first connection then the new connection will automatiaclly appear on the wizard.
 If you del all connections the wizard won't automatically display that stupid dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty model, then in the Model Browser or explorer properties for file.edmx right-click Model.edmx or YourModel.edmx. Choose Update Model From Database.

This way is similar to creating the model from database using ado.net..