# Entity Data Model wizard disappears SQL Anywhere 17

Tags: entity-framework-6, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to make a new model using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Anywhere 17. I followed exactly these steps.

http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/37fb9e8558e94547b66156b9298be16f.html

But when I go through Entity Data Model wizard, it disappears after the following screen.
[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue using SQL Anywhere 16 and EF6. It does not seem to matter which EF6.x version I'm using. Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I got same Issue and able to resolve by following these step.

1. Open server explorer tab-
2. Delete all existing data connections-
3. Rebuild your project-

   [image: Server Explorer]

After this Entity Data Model wizard will not disappears.